# Can Antlr ignore some of the keyword?

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, antlr3

I'm new to Antlr but I'm trying to change some of the Grammar from my existing project. The example of the grammar looks like this

```
...

factor 
    : ava | NOT^ factor | (LPAREN! expr RPAREN!) ;
    
ava
    : key=ALPHANUM EQUALS value=ALPHANUM ;

AND     
    : ('and' | 'AND');

OR  
    : ('or' | 'OR'); 
    

NOT
    : ('not' | 'NOT');  


ALPHANUM 
    : (ALPHA | DIGIT | LIMITED_SYMBOLS)+ ;
        
    
WHITESPACE 
    : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

fragment ALPHA 
        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment DIGIT 
    : '0'..'9' ;
    
fragment LIMITED_SYMBOLS
    : ('.' | '!' | '@' | '#' | '$' | '%' | '^' | '&' | '*' | '-' | '_' | '+' | '~' | ':' | '/' | '?' | '|');
```

The grammar is supposed to parse something like this `a=10 AND s=1 AND s=2` or `((a=9 AND s=1) AND s=2)`.

The question is is it possible to ignore anything that's not `s={ANYTHING}`. So from the examples above. The AST will be reduced to

`s=1 AND s=2`, `((s=1) AND s=2)`

Is this even possible by just changing the grammar?

Comment: I'm new to Antlr so I might have misunderstood it completely. What I'm trying to do it is I would like to build a grammar that only looks at a boolean expression with just one key,pair. In the example above that means it would just be b={value}. From your example (a=b) and (c=a) then that expression would be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even possible by just changing the grammar?

No.

For sure there's something possible with tree rewrites, but it'd involve a lot of target specific code being embedded in your grammar. The best solution would be to just parse the entire input, and after that, walk your AST and discard certain sub-trees that start with `s` (in plain code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will look into that and ask more relevant questions.